# Searching for a <td>, and editing the contents of another <td>

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm looking to write a piece of a larger program which I would like to search the source html on a website for one of two values "Index 1" or "Index 2" within a unknown number of  tags, then edit the  tag above the  containing "Index 1" or Index 2" (still within the same table row ) to denote a checkbox is checked or unchecked. As an example: I want to achieve all "Index 1" checkboxes on while "Index 2" checkboxes are off. I'm not entirely sure the best way to approach this and am looking for guidance in the right direction. Here is some mock code which may help

```
<fieldset  class="stackedSection">
<legend >someThings</legend>    <table>
      <tr>
    <td><input name="someId[]" type="checkbox" value="001"></input></td>
    <td><a href="associated?id=001">nameOfAssociatedID001</a> index 1        (<a href="device?id=a01">name1</a>)</td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td><input name="someId[]" type="checkbox" value="002" checked></input></td>
    <td><a href="associated?id=002">nameOfAssociatedID002</a> index 1        (<a href="device?id=a02">name2</a>)</td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td><input name="someId[]" type="checkbox" value="003" checked></input></td>
    <td><a href="associated?id=003">nameOfAssociatedID003</a> index 1        (<a href="device?id=a03">name3</a>)</td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td><input name="someId[]" type="checkbox" value="004" checked></input></td>
    <td><a href="some?id=004">nameOfAssociatedID004</a> index 2        (<a href="device?id=a04">name4</a>)</td>
  </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put them inside a form then give the radio buttons same names then HTML will do the trick for you.

Or if there are more than one radio that you want to check it is advisable that you use checkboxes and just iterate in javascript (using jquery).

Example:

```
$('#tableID tr td').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
     if(this.value == "Index 1"){
         this.checked = true;
     }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I explained the problem properly, though your response gives me some ideas to work with. To be a little more clear, the mock code listed above is from another website which I am looking to scrape data from. for the

Comment: ...I'm not exactly understanding where your suggestion of "put them inside a form" is coming from.

Comment: Well if it was radio buttons then you would use input tags. And basically input tags should be inside a form, now, since multiple items will be checked i suggest you use checkboxes then just manipulate it in a Javascript just like my code above. You don't need to put it in a form tag anymore since you are going to iterate it inside a table.